# Easily extensible DNS server with custom interceptor

Tags: java, linux, dns, ip, interceptor

I'm looking for a small and – most important – easily extensible DNS server.

I'm not planning to actually resolve any addresses. This should be done via other configured public servers.

I want to intercept the resolved address, do some checks, and then return either the resolved address or a dummy IP address. The important cut point for me is after resolving, but one before would also be nice.

The server has to run on Linux. The programming language with which the interception is written is ideally Java, but anything else would be OK too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RubyDNS](http://www.codeotaku.com/projects/rubydns/) looks interesting to me.